# Strange dictionary in swift

Tags: swift, dictionary, swift-playground

If I try something like this in a Swift playground:

```
let dic = ["1" : "!", "2" : "@","3" : "#"]
print(dic)
```

It prints:

> ["2": "@", "1": "!", "3": "#"]

And when I run it again it prints:

> ["1": "!", "2": "@", "3": "#"]

And then:

> ["3": "#", "2": "@", "1": "!"]

Is it ok? I use Xcode 10 beta.

Comment: _**Is it ok?**_ OK. Swift `Dictionary` is not order-preserving. Within the same invocation of an app, the order is stable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Becuase dictionaries have key pair values (a key being "1" and value being "!") it doesnt sort them in order like an array it will be different each time, (Where an array stores a value at a position that it was added) you can grab the value of a dictionary by knowing the key so it doesnt matter